# Handling data from select option form in PHP

Tags: php

I have basic login form :

```
....
 <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="user_name"/>
 <input type="password" required autocomplete="off" name="password"/>
 ....
```

But I want user choose username from section option instead of input username from keyboard. So I make a select option form

```
                     <div class="col-md-2">

                    <select name="Grade" id="Grade"   
                    data-live-search="true" class="chosen selectpicker form-control" required>
                    <option value="">Select Grade</option>

                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-12" id="lable1"><id="lable1">user</div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                       <!--select username-->
                    <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="user" id="user"  autofocus="autofocus" required>
                        <option value="">Select an Option</option>                            
                    </select>
                  <!--select username-->   
                    </div>
```

How can I hanlde data from select option form instead of input username to

```
<input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="user_name"/>
```

Comment: You do it exactly the same way.  Just make sure you're using the correct element name.

Comment: I tried 
`<select class="selectpicker form-control" name="user_name" id="user"  autofocus="autofocus" required>` but not work.

Comment: from where the Option values of username get populated ? from mysql database ?

Comment: "but not work" is not a helpful problem statement. _In what way_ does it not work? What is the expected result? What is the actual result? Are you getting any errors? If so, what exactly are they? Also, you're not actually showing any PHP code here. If that's what this question is really about, then you should show that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Accessing HTML `<form>` elements in PHP

All HTML elements in a HTML form can access by PHP with their *name* with these variables:

`$_POST['NAME']` or `$_GET['NAME']`

**GET or POST depends on your form action.**
And the value of these Variables are the *value* attribute of the HTML element

As described in form.guide [Handling select box (drop-down list) in a PHP form](http://form.guide/php-form/php-form-select.html)

This is an example for *select* element

**HTML :**

> ```
> <p>
> What is your Gender?
> <select name="formGender">
>   <option value="">Select...</option>
>   <option value="M">Male</option>
>   <option value="F">Female</option>
> </select>
> </p>
> ```

**PHP :**

> ```
> <?php
>
> if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) ) //IF FORM SUBMIT IS PRESSED
> {
>   $varMovie = $_POST['formMovie']; // Other form inputs
>   $varName = $_POST['formName']; // Other form inputs
>   $varGender = $_POST['formGender']; //Our Select element
>   $errorMessage = "";
>
>   // - - - snip - - - 
> }
>
> ?>
> ```

### In your example :

**HTML :**

```
<!--select username-->
      <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="user" id="user" autofocus="autofocus" required>
             <option value="user1">USER ONE</option>  
             <option value="user2">USER TWO</option>                           
      </select>
<!--select username-->
```

**And you can use in your PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['user']) ){
    $name=$_POST['user']; //user1 if USER ONE selected or user2 if second one...

}
```